# How do I create an application from my site?

Tags: java, android, html

When I get a web view output for my site, nothing happens after entering the number and clicking the button to send the verification code.

But when I enter the URL in each browser and after entering the number click on the button, I get the confirmation code.
my address URL: https://app.my30t.ir/login
I've recently tried testing sample browser source code in GitHub but I don't get a normal result. please guide me.

```
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

    private WebView myWebView;
    private EditText editText;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        myWebView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.activity_main_webview);
        WebSettings webSettings = myWebView.getSettings();
        webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        myWebView.loadUrl("https://app.my30t.ir/login");
        myWebView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());
        myWebView.setWebViewClient(new TutorialWebViewClient());
        editText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText);
        editText.setOnEditorActionListener(new TextView.OnEditorActionListener() {
                @Override
                public boolean onEditorAction(TextView v, int actionId, KeyEvent event) {
                    boolean handled = false;
                    if(actionId == EditorInfo.IME_ACTION_SEND) {
                        myWebView.loadUrl(editText.getText().toString());
                        handled = true;
                    }
                    return handled;
                }
            });
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
   editText.setOnEditorActionListener(new TextView.OnEditorActionListener() {
                @Override
                public boolean onEditorAction(TextView v, int actionId, KeyEvent event) {
                    boolean handled = false;
                    if((actionId == EditorInfo.IME_ACTION_SEARCH
            || actionId == EditorInfo.IME_ACTION_DONE
            || event.getAction() == KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN
            && event.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_ENTER) {
                        myWebView.loadUrl(editText.getText().toString());
                        handled = true;
                    }
                    return handled;
                }
            });
```